# List of dictionaries - tracking words frequency per file

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary

I have written some code to count word frequency in multiple text files and store them in a dictionary.

I have been trying to find a method to keep a running total per file of counts for each word in a form something like:

`word1 [1] [20] [30] [22] 
word2 [5] [7] [0] [4]`

I have tried using counters but I've not been able to find an appropriate method/data structure for this yet.

```
import string 
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
import glob
import os


# Words to remove
noise_words_set = {'the','to','of','a','in','is',...etc...}


# Find files
path = r"C:\Users\Logs"
os.chdir(path)
print("Processing files...")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):

    # Read file
    txt = open("{}\{}".format(path, file),'r', encoding="utf8").read()

    # Remove punctuation
    for punct in string.punctuation:
        txt = txt.replace(punct,"")

    # Split into words and make lower case
    words = [item.lower() for item in txt.split()]

    # Remove unintersting words
    words = [w for w in words if w not in noise_words_set]

    # Make a dictionary of words
    D = defaultdict(int)
    for word in words:
        D[word] += 1

    # Add to some data structure (?) that keeps count per file
    #...word1 [1] [20] [30] [22]
    #...word2 [5] [7] [0] [4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using almost your entire structure!

```
from collections import Counter

files = dict() # this may be better as a list, tbh

table = str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file) as f:
        word_count = Counter()
        for line in f:
            word_count += Counter([word.lower() for word in line.translate(table) if
                                  word not in noise_words_set])
    files[file] = word_count # if list: files.append(word_count)
```

If you want them translated to some dictionary, do this afterwards

```
words_count = dict()
for file in files:
    for word,value in file.items():
        try: words_count[word].append(value)
        except KeyError: words_count[word] = [value]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely rebuild this in a class. That will allow you to store the items you want as global objects (i.e. you can have a function that runs over a single file and adds it in).

That being said I would build a defaultdict that contains a dict.

`defaultdict(dict)`

I would structure it with the following protocol (storing both the total and individual file amounts in the same data structure):

`{word1:{filename1:5, filename2:20, total:25}, word2:{filename1:10, filename2:13, total:23}, ...}`

In order to build this you would need to move the defaultdict call outside the for loop over files. I went ahead and restructured your code for you:

```
import string 
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
import glob
import os


# Words to remove
noise_words_set = {'the','to','of','a','in','is',...etc...}


# Find files
path = r"C:\Users\Logs"
os.chdir(path)
print("Processing files...")

#global defaultdict
D = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

#global counter (for file #)
counter = 1

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):

    #create name for file number
    file_number = "file{number}".format(number=counter)

    # Read file
    txt = open("{}\{}".format(path, file),'r', encoding="utf8").read()

    # Remove punctuation
    for punct in string.punctuation:
        txt = txt.replace(punct,"")

    # Split into words and make lower case
    words = [item.lower() for item in txt.split()]

    # Remove unintersting words
    words = [w for w in words if w not in noise_words_set]

    # Make a dictionary of words
    for word in words:
        #add count to the file and the total
        D[word][file_number] += 1
        D[word]["total"] += 1

    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you:

```
wordRef = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

... some code ...

for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):

    ... some code ...

    for word in words:
        wordRef[word][file] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`D = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
   ...your code...
   for word in words:
       D[word][file] +=1`